# CSS - responsive / Android

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am building a mobile website. Now I need to catch every Android/iPhone-gadget and get the same view on every mobile device. What I do:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

In css later:

```
media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    body {
        width:480px;
    } 
    etc..
}
```

On every iPhone and some Android gadgets, I get a good result.

But on some Android gadgets, I have a very large mobile website,

So, do I need to work with percentages on mobile website?

Comment: what exactly is your problem ? all responsive sites are built with percentage !

Comment: So you are only wanting a site to work on ios and android? what about over smartphones? as above you'll need to make a percentage based site. try reading mobile first (http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using only percentages and using min-width/max-width.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you. Because there are three method for full responsive mobile design

1. Responsive Web Design
2. Dynamic Serving
3. Separate URLs

1st one is using [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
.2nd is using [HTTP Headers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving)
3rd is Separate URLs
in your case Http header method is best because it caught the device and browser that from request is being proced